# Execute packageBin task for sub modules in a multi module SBT project

Tags: sbt

I have a multi module SBT project. It has three modules; core, connector and integration. Sub module integration depends on both core and connector. 
I want to writing a custom task for project integration to package every thing for deployment. From that task I should be able to create jar files of all sub modules and put them in to a lib folder along with other project dependencies. I've managed to get all the library dependencies using

```
fullClasspath in Runtime
```

With that I'm also getting the compiled class folders of two depending projects(core, connector). But what I want is to include jar files created from core and connector.

I can run the package command separately in my sub modules and copy the jars from my custom task. But I think there should be a way to create the jar files of sub modules from my custom task directly. Currently I'm creating the jar file of integration sub module which this custom task is binded to using

```
packageBin in Compile
```

I think there should be a way to execute same command in other modules from my custom task. Is it possible to do this in SBT?